# Where should my brackets be in relation to the text for Arabic languages?

Tags: arabic, right-to-left, brackets, bidi

Our application automatically modifies the layout of Arabic text when it is followed by a bracket and I was wondering whether this was the correct behaviour or not?

The application shows items in the following format:

```
[ID of structure](version)
```

So version 1.5 of the English structure "stackoverflow" would be displayed as:

```
stackoverflow(1.5)
```

*Note:* the brackets need to be displayed. There is no space between the ID and the first bracket. The brackets simply encompass the version. The brackets could have been any character but it's far too late to switch to a different character now!

This works fine for left to right languages, but for Arabic languages the structures appear in the form:

```
ستاكوفيرفلوو(1.0)
```

I am not an Arabic speaker and I need to know if this is actually correct. Is the Arabic format the equivalent of the English format or has something gone horribly wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text in Arabic should be shown like:

ستاكوفيرفلوو(1.0) ‏

I added the html entity of RLM / Right-to-left Mark `&rlm;` in order to fix the text. You should do so if your application doesn't support Bidi native-ly. You can add the RLM by these ways:

```
HTML Entity (decimal)   &#8207;
HTML Entity (hex)   &#x200f;
HTML Entity (named) &rlm;
How to type in Microsoft Windows    Alt +200F
UTF-8 (hex) 0xE2 0x80 0x8F (e2808f)
UTF-8 (binary)  11100010:10000000:10001111
UTF-16 (hex)    0x200F (200f)
UTF-16 (decimal)    8,207
UTF-32 (hex)    0x0000200F (200f)
UTF-32 (decimal)    8,207
C/C++/Java source code  "\u200F"
Python source code  u"\u200F"
```

*(note: StackOverflow right transliteration is ستاك-أوفرفلو)*

Comment: Thank you for answering with how it should be and this shows as I suspected that my output is totally wrong. I didn't want to say on my original question but this isn't HTML but Flex so I can't use the RLM. Thanks again. Now I know that this output is wrong I can look at alternate solutions.

Comment: @Phil you can add RLM by many ways, one of them is type it with keyboard(windows): Alt +200F

Comment: Note that you need a registry key set to type Unicode code points with `Alt` in Windows. Set `HKEY_Current_User/Control Panel/Input Method/EnableHexNumpad` to `"1"`, log off, and log back in (or reboot). For more info, see [How to enter Unicode characters in Microsoft Windows](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm).